# No new mail icon in panel when using evolution

Tags: ubuntu, email, notifications, evolution, gnome-panel

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, kernel 2.6.32-21-generic, with Evolution 2.83.3.

I have noticed that when I get a new email, it never shows a new mail icon in the panel. I had the same problem with 9.10, and I thought the problem would go away when I upgraded to 10.04.

I have checked the properties in Mail preferences:

```
Play sound - yes
Display a notification - yes
Indicate new messages in panel - yes
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just ran into this same problem. Are you missing the Mail icon completely from the panel? I was. Apparently, the Mail notification icon is part of the Indicator Applet, which is the sound and mail icons. If you want the Mail icon back, just add that applet to the panel. This [post](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/restore-missing-volume-button-to-system-tray-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-10-04/) explains it.